# sdl unicode text

Tags: c++, unicode, utf-8, sdl

I want to show an unicode text in my sdl program , but it doesnt render on screen correctly.
It renders from end to begining and the characters render seperatly (They should connect to each other)

[You can see a screen shot here http://up.vatandownload.com/images/ea8d1c2kxpk5ehbjv2.png](http://up.vatandownload.com/images/ea8d1c2kxpk5ehbjv2.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SDL does not implement full Unicode text layout. It works for many languages, but Arabic (which has incredibly complex layout and glyph-selection rules) is not one of them. You will need to use either Pango or ICU's layout class to do your text layout if you need Arabic support.